# Applying background to ::first-line

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is this effect:

[image]

```
h3{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
h3::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

With the code I currently have, the line would go straight through the text. Therefore I tried to apply a background to the text to cover up the line:

```
h3::first-line{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: inline;
    background: white;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/3PagQ/

Any idea?

An extra question: how can I increase the width of the gap between the text and the line? I tried `padding: 0 10px` and it's not working.

Comment: I tried to use :before and :after but couldn't quite get it right: http://jsfiddle.net/3PagQ/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a negative `z-index` to the `::before` pseudo element ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PagQ/9/))

```css
h3::before {
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

I think the only way to have a margin between the border and pseudo element is to use `box-shadow`:

```css
h3::first-line {
    /* .. */
    box-shadow: 10px 0 white,
               -10px 0 white;
}
```

Note that margin & padding don't apply to `::first-line`.

Comment: This is a very clever use of box shadow! Thanks it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Made this btn which is really similar to what your wanna do here?
try it out see if you like it its responsive aswell and supported down to IE7

It is also content aware, can be centered, left or right or you can add mutiple boxes and justify them along the line

http://nomis.dk/cool-responsive-button/
also made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nomisweb/GJHvD/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="btn">
        <div class="btn__horizontal-border"></div>
        <div class="btn__border">
            <div class="btn__text">
                Here is a button
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn {
    width:100%;
    height:31px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}
.btn__horizontal-border {
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.btn__border {
    display:inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    height: 31px;
    line-height:31px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.btn__text {
    border: 2px red solid;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: block;
}
.btn__text:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: That’s a lot of wrappers.

Comment: @minitech that is in order to do a IE7 support it needed and border and responsive and content aware and so on

Answer (score 0):

You could have an outer `div` for positioning, then a `hr` tag which can be styled by CSS, with the text layered on top:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm84h/)**

---

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <hr><div class="heading">Title</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading {
    position:relative;
    left:80px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    background-color:white;
    width:45px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Indeed this works, but the main reason I used pseudo selectors is because I don't want wrappers.

Comment: I see, is that to keep your HTML super clean?

Comment: Cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: Cool. I'll keep an eye out for CSS-wrapper-savers in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be much simpler and will work in older browsers if you are ok with assigning the name of the heading using CSS.

HTML:

```
<h3></h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    font: 20px/1 Serif;
}

h3:before {
    content: "Title";
    position: absolute;
    margin: -10px 0 0 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

And, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sq3qv/.

Comment: Interesting answer, however it's not very practical.

Comment: Whether it is practical or not depends on the situation.  If a developer is looking for a solution to work in older browsers, then that'll work.  Also, it is possible to define the name of the heading within a data- attribute and then use attr() function when creating a new element: http://jsfiddle.net/26TzM/.  attr() is supported from IE8 and up.

Comment: Sure you can use `data-` for the content, but now the HTML becomes meaningless and confusing. For example, normally to set the content of an element you do `element.innerHTML`, but now you would have to do `element.dataset.content`. There are much more problems behind this method, and on the MDN [they actually discourage developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#Issues) to store visible content in data-* atributes.

Comment: Well, sure.  We all would like to live in a web utopia where pages are rendered the same way on all browsers without hacks, polyfills and the such.  That's hardly the reality.  That's why the theme of my answer is a solution that works in older browsers.  Keep in mind that even ::first-line pseudo-element is supported only as far back as IE9.  And truth be told, a more universal solution will require additional markup, because neither :before nor :after work in old browsers (e.g., IE6).

Comment: Also keep in mind that ::first-line is very very limited with respect to CSS that can be applied to it.  In your code and in the code for some of the answers, setting position to relative or absolute, or setting z-index on the ::first-line is rather moot.  You cannot apply transforms to it, etc.  A few text effects is about it.